# help with cabal install package shadowing errors

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've run into the same error for two unrelated packages now, missingpy and monadiccp.

```
> cabal install -p -v monadiccp
```

(after some output)

```
Creating dist/build (and its parents)
/usr/local/haskell/bin/ghc --make -package-name monadiccp-0.7.0 -hide-all-packages -fbuilding-cabal-package -i -idist/build -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -Ilib -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -package-id Monatron-0.3.1-360ddfdcf06bcd34f1ed9c1f1c375202 -package-id base-4.3.1.0-1554f26e1cc1c87f47464e927dddbd20 -package-id containers-0.4.0.0-8781485edb2ac0db733a9f9c72e27945 -package-id haskell98-1.1.0.1-0a04bcdb24934b6be516a3abfc033021 -package-id mtl-2.0.1.0-91f62d81c946aa60137dcc008e554a3a -package-id pretty-1.0.1.2-6970e62db724fea03caad23f58dd8f86 -package-id random-1.0.0.3-9024b40453c28359a37c49ce4e776f6e -O -XHaskell98 Data.Expr.Sugar Control.CP.SearchTree Control.CP.Transformers Control.CP.ComposableTransformers Control.CP.Solver Control.CP.PriorityQueue Control.CP.Queue Control.CP.FD.Interface Control.CP.FD.OvertonFD.OvertonFD Control.CP.FD.OvertonFD.Sugar Control.CP.EnumTerm Control.CP.FD.Solvers Control.CP.FD.Gecode.CodegenSolver Control.CP.FD.Model Control.CP.FD.Example Data.Expr.Data Data.Expr.Util Data.Linear Control.CP.FD.Gecode.Common Control.CP.FD.OvertonFD.Domain Control.CP.FD.SimpleFD Control.CP.FD.Graph Control.CP.FD.Decompose Control.CP.FD.FD Control.CP.Debug Control.Mixin.Mixin Control.CP.SearchSpec.Language Control.CP.SearchSpec.Generator Language.CPP.Syntax.AST Language.CPP.Pretty
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id random-1.0.0.3-9024b40453c28359a37c49ce4e776f6e: 
    random-1.0.0.3-9024b40453c28359a37c49ce4e776f6e is shadowed by package random-1.0.0.3-15ae8b1458485ee9647f74174e442c33
    (use -v for more information)
World file is already up to date.
```

For `missingpy`, ghc will work if the `-package-id random...` is changed to the correct version, but I don't know how to install it after that.

Any workarounds would be much appreciated. I deleted all of `~/.cabal` and `~/.ghc`, but no luck.

#### additional info

- ghc info is here, [ http://pastebin.com/jk40VPgw ]. This is my SuSE machine, where I built ghc 7.0.4 from source using ghc 6.12, as well as the latest Haskell Platform. (which was made for ghc 7.0.3, but I think that's okay).
- also tried this on another machine [ http://pastebin.com/Digntv4K ]. that one had the Haskell Platform installed via system packages I think.

Comment: Could you supply the version numbers of ghc and cabal-install? The output of ghc-pkg list would also be useful.

Comment: If you've deleted all of `~/.ghc` and the problem persists, then it's certain to be a problem with your global package database.  That's a lot harder to fix, since deleting the global package database will break GHC.  Perhaps remove and reinstall the Haskell Platform, and then be careful to ensure that you're only installing new packages in the user database in the future.

Comment: I tried deleting most GHC packages in /usr/local (hopefully that got rid of the Haskell Platform), reinstalled GHC, removed ~/.cabal and ~/.ghc, and retried, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev)?  It's probably best if you start from a clean system, install only the Haskell Platform, and then use cabal-dev to sandbox each codebase you're using.