# how to use "cabal configure" / Setup.hs for local buildling?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to work around another bug with the regular `cabal install` ( [help with cabal install package shadowing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877872/help-with-cabal-install-package-shadowing-errors) ). When I try to run `Setup.hs` after using cabal to unpack a package (in this case, `monadiccp`), I get dependency errors.

```
monadiccp-0.7.0> cabal configure  
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring monadiccp-0.7.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
monatron -any
```

This happens with the above command, `runghc Setup.py --user`, `--global`, etc. Do I need to use the `--package-db` flag, and if so, what are its semantics?

Thanks in advance.

### edit

So sorry, I can't believe I forgot to mention, `monatron` is indeed installed.

```
/home/gatoatigrado/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.4/package.conf.d
   HTTP-4000.1.1
   HUnit-1.2.2.3
   MaybeT-0.1.2
   Monatron-0.3.1
```

Comment: Is `monatron` installed? `cabal configure` does not install dependencies; you need to use `cabal install` for that.

Comment: For something like this you may want to check out cabal-dev.

Comment: @hammar yes, it is installed, sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: hmm... looks like the cabal-install bootstrapping script gets around this... I'll take a look when I'm not super-busy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`cabal-dev`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev) to sidestep the bug with `cabal install`. If you still need to install dependencies first instead of having `cabal-dev install` do it all in one go, run `cabal-dev install --only-dependencies`.

Comment: And now instead of `cabal-dev` I assume most would like to go for `cabal sandbox`.