# How can one register a package built with cabal-dev?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I was able to use `cabal-dev` to build some packages that `cabal` was having issues with. ( [help with cabal install package shadowing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877872/help-with-cabal-install-package-shadowing-errors) ). How does one then install and use them? I tried copying the package database files into the `~/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.4/package.conf.d` folder, and running `ghc-pkg recache --user`, but no luck. (They do show up in `ghc-pkg` now though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, though it's more crap I have to put in my zshrc...

```
export GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=$HOME/cabal-dev/packages-7.0.4.conf:$HOME/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.0.4/package.conf.d:/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.4/package.conf.d
```

hope it helps someone. (of course you'll have to adjust paths appropriately; the old ones can be found by running `ghc-pkg list`).

Comment: Maybe is worth to fill a bug in dev site